# Can I use claims data to insert CreatedBy user data into custom tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have slight architecture issue.
I have IdentityServer solution, to authenticate user with Identity user store(with user in database). I have login functionality here and register functionality, so I have to use DbContext here. I have another solution API where I hold custom tables which are not Identity tables. All tables are in same database.

Now when I add new record through API, I somehow want to connect CreadetBy with Identity user. I know I can get info about user from Claims, and then insert while creating new row, but is that good practice?

Another question is, should I move registration operation out of IdentityServer project, and only use Login functionality towards identity user store there and put registration to API, so I don't duplicate additional fields for ApplicationUser in two places?

Comment: So you have two contexts, one for identity and one for custom tables? With the user table in the database you mean the AspNetUsers table? Do you also have a users table in your custom context?

Comment: yes i do have user tables in custom context, but i added because i though i have to link it with custom table. i want to somehow only keep in one place without duplication. you know what i mean. if i create custom table Cars which has connection with AspNetUsers table, do i even have to make a link, or could i just make generic field CreatedBy, and fill that custom table with User.Identity.Name via claims, and then later if i want to guery which user created some car with AspNetUsers I just do it with getting the car table USERID and query aspnetUsers with that USERID? do you know what i mean?

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand you should maintain a seperation of concerns. You should never have a relation between tables that do not share the same context. This means that Cars can never link to AspNetUsers.

It is about the meaning of the objects and the fields. For example, it seems that IdentityUser and CustomUser are equal, but they are not. The IdentityUser has all the information needed to identify the user as where CustomUser has all the information needed for the custom model. In fact, you can have CustomUsers which do not have a login account.

Also consider the emailaddress. It seems redundant to have this field in both contexts, but actually I could use my Google account to login while I want to receive updates on my custom emailaddress.

So what is the meaning of the CreatedBy field and how are you going to use it? If it is part of the custom context (like for reports), then you should have a CustomUser table and relate to that table. If you just want to check this for administration purposes, than it may suffice to store the username. Are you going to query by that field? Do you need additional information, like CustomUserAddress?

If done well, I don't think you actually have redundant fields. Since they all have different purpose / meaning.

In any case, you don't want to relate beyond the context. And you don't want to end up sending lists of id's to retrieve information from another context.

The problem is that you want to link the current user. The identity token is used to identify the user. This means nothing to your resource. But the access token contains information about the actual user in the resource.

By keeping authorization close to the resource, you can extend the authorization user with CustomUserId. Add this information to the access token, since it is part of the authorization. It tells the resource that the user can only access data from the specified user.

With [access token].customUserId you can match the CustomUser. Thus CreatedBy should have the value of CustomUser.Id.

I would also like to recommend this article: https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/

Comment: Nice explanation! But how do I add CustomUserId to the access token, my Identity Server project can't access my CustomUser model in the API project. And when do I create my CustomUser? The IdentityServer creates an IdentityUser upon registration, how can my API project know when to create the relating CustomUser? Is there a tutorial or an example on how to do this?

Comment: @Skullbox I think there are two options. 1) If you won't need additional information you can add a 'sub' column to CustomerUser and use 'sub'  in claims to identify the user. If no CustomerUser record exists (sub column can't be matched by sub-claim), create the new CustomerUser. 2) Upon registration you'll have to add the identifier as claim (in AspNetUserClaims). Generate a guid as ID or call the API to register a CustomerUser and use the obtained CustomerUser.Id.