# Identity Server 4 user model relations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am quite new to .Net Core and Identity Server 4, I followed several tutorials and got an Identity Server with Asp .Net Core Identity running.

Then I have a separate API project with restricted routes that works well.

So let's say I want users to be able to post comments to this api.

In my Identity Server project I have a model called "ApplicationUser" extending "IdentityUser".

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

In my API project I have a "Comment" model:

```
public class Comment
{
    public long Id { get; set; };
    public string Text { get; set; };
}
```

Now I want to know which User posted the comment, so I added a foreign key to the user and a pointer to ApplicationUser in my Comment model

```
public class Comment
{
    public long Id { get; set; };
    public string Text { get; set; };

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

But since "ApplicationUser" is in my IdentityServer project, I need to add a Project dependency in my Api project pointing to the IdentityServer project.

Then in my "ApplicationUser" model I want to have a one-to-many relation to the comments posted by that User, like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

But here I am encountering a problem since my "IdentityServer" project doesn't have access to my "Comment" model in the API project and if I try to add dependency to that project then I get an error of "circular dependency".

So I guess I am doing this the wrong way. How can I access users from the IdentityServer project in my API project models and vice-versa in the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: Your IdentityServer should have nothing to do with Comments and ApplicationUsers. The IdentityServer is independent from your API. So keep your stuff on the API side and use the IdentityServer just for authenticating.

Comment: Ok, but then I guess I need a AppicationUser model in my API project, how do I connect a certain logged in User to my AppicationUser model?

Comment: I'd use a database for storing the users, let the IdentityServer access the database when a user wants to login. The IdentityServer returns an `access_token` (which has a user_id included) that is then sent by the client to your API, where you can retrieve the user.

Comment: So I don't need the ApplicationUser in the IdentityServer project? Instead I should have a user model in my API project which I then can connect to my other models?

Comment: Why are you using IdentityServer? Do you plan to let other clients access your api? You can have the ApplicationUser in both the IdentityServer and your API, if both are accessing ApplicationUser in a database. So model your class after your database, and you can use it in both projects just fine. But you can also model a user with just a username and a password. The IdentityServer does not need comments in its user class.

Comment: Why are you using longs for ids?

Comment: @Mardoxx Any reasons why not to?

Comment: @moritzg When you say that the user_id is included in the access_token, what do you mean? My API wants to know the user_id so I can use it when saving a new comment posted by the user, how can the API get that user_id from the access_token? My access_token is just a long set of characters, can I decode it to get that info?

Comment: Ok I think you should read up on OIDC and oAuth2. The `access_token` is basically an encoded JSON. For example you can paste your `access_token` [here](https://jwt.io/) to decode it and see everything it contains.

Comment: Ok thanks @moritzg! Will do!

Comment: This may also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096327/can-i-use-claims-data-to-insert-createdby-user-data-into-custom-tables/44097676#44097676

Comment: @RuardvanElburg wow! that is exactly what I wanted to ask but better formulated. Does anyone know a good tutorial that shows how to solve this problem?